# Why BLE pairing request dialog appears two times?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

When we use "nRF Connect" or "BLE Scanner" (BLE, not BT) APPs on Google pixel with Android 12 (e.g. Pixel 3 and Pixel 5) to connect a BLE device, it will pop up the pairing request dialog twice. But when we use the APPs on Google pixel with Android 11 to connect a BLE device, it only popup 1 pairing request dialog. Does somebody have the same issue? What's the difference between the pairing of Android 12 and Android 11?

Comment: The pairing dialog is an internal system operation, not controlled by code. If it appears twice it could simply be considered a bug.

Comment: This also happens for me on an updated version of android 11

Comment: I am also facing the same issue when trying to repair to a device the pop up is appearing twice on Android 12 or above.

Comment: According to this link, it only happens on Android 12 devices, if the periperhal initiates the bonding... https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/507
Haven't been able to confirm this hypothesis